# horizontal space constraint in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I have label inside tableview cell
how can I update the value of constant to -65

I have tried doing

```
[cell.address.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.address.leadingAnchor constant:-65].active = YES;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drag it as an outlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leadCon;
```

Then change its constant

```
_leadCon.constant = -65;
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

> Tip : What you currently do will add another constraint which will make a conflict between the 1 in IB , hence unexpected results

Comment: it does not build and gives this error The adrressleading outlet from the screen2 to the NSLayoutConstraint is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. [12]

Comment: you need to expand constraints section and drag the constraint itself not the address label

Comment: as it was custom cell so I had to put the property in subclass , it is working now